# nil pointer evaluating interface {}.KubeVersion

Tags: kubernetes, charts, kubernetes-helm

When I write func in _helpers.tpl in helm chart.

```
{{- define "hqxtest.kubeVersion" -}}
  {{- .Capabilities.KubeVersion.Version -}}
{{- end }}

{{- define "hqxtest.ingress.apiVersion" -}}
  {{- if ge .Capabilities.KubeVersion.Version "v1.19.0" }}
      {{ print "networking.k8s.io/v1" }}
  {{- else }}
    {{ print "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1" }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

helm reports an error just like this:

> "executing "hqxtest.ingress.apiVersion" at <.Capabilities.KubeVersion.Version>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.KubeVersion"

but when I use configMap as a test, just like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: hqx-test-configmap
data:
  {{- if ge .Capabilities.KubeVersion.Version "v1.19" }}
  val: {{ printf "networking.k8s.io/v1" }}
  {{- else }}
  val: {{ printf "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1" }}
  {{- end }}
```

it shows right when I use helm, just like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: hqx-test-configmap
data:
  val: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

I want  to know why the func hqxtest.ingress.apiVersion shows this error:

> "nil pointer evaluating interface {}.KubeVersion"

Comment: How are you calling (`template` or `include`) these support templates?  You can get that error if the parameter you pass isn't the top-level Helm object.

Comment: @DavidMaze thank u my friend, I find the reason why this happend. In the upper layer of the apiverison field, there is also a for loop, which causes the scope to change, for it causes the problems of the  nil in .Capabilities.